# Issue with getting Access token using forge DA

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to get an access token using Forge DA using the code below. But it throws the following [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVyVx.png):

> An exception of type 'Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Error calling Authenticate: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Here is my code:

```cs
TwoLeggedApi oAuth = new TwoLeggedApi();
dynamic token = await  oAuth.AuthenticateAsync(
   txtClientId.Text,
   txtClientSecret.Text,
   oAuthConstants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS ,
   new Scope[] { Scope.BucketRead, Scope.BucketCreate, Scope.DataRead, Scope.DataWrite });
```

Comment: If you could edit the question and add the exception that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the error is calling out connection make sure your system can reach our service from your network (check proxy, firewall etc, can you reach our other endpoints?) and it supports TLS 1.2 - see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/upcoming-forge-system-upgrade-tls-12-upgrade-date-moved-oct-31)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the Design Automation SDK [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-design.automation). This one allows you to access the new V3 API while the [one](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client) I presume you are using can only access the now deprecated V2 API.

Here's a [sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-.net-custom.activity.sample) that uses this SDK.

Comment: OP was having problems getting access token so the DA version doesnt matter here...